# why ImageView height isn't applied?

Tags: android, android-view

i have two imageview in my xml within linear layout.after that i have viewfilpper.in MotionEvent.ACTION_UP of TouchEvent i'm changing the height of imageview
as

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview1)).getLayoutParams().height=23;   
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview1)).getLayoutParams().width=23;
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2)).getLayoutParams().height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2)).getLayoutParams().width=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

but in view when i touch any editText field then changes apply

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2)).invalidate();
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2)).refreshDrawableState();
```

and this isn't working too

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview1)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(23,23));
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

by above statements my problem isn't solved

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that when you call `getLayoutParams()` you receive and immutable param object. Consider something like `setLayoutParamams(new LayoutParams(...))`

Comment: i have changed my code to                                                                                  ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview1)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(23,23));
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview2)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));    but now my app is crashing